# Editor template doesn't work after calling Ajax.BeginForm and Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I created an editor template for enums which was working fine, until I decided to use Ajax.BeginForm. The property `status` has the following definition:

```
<DisplayName("Status")>
<UIHint("enum")>
Public Property status As String
```

I already tried the following approachs:

```
@Using Ajax.BeginForm("New", "Os", Nothing)
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.status, "Enum", New With { .enumType = GetType(OsStatus)})
End Using
```

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("New", "Os", Nothing)

@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.status, "Enum", New With { .enumType = GetType(OsStatus)})
```

```
@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.status, "Enum", New With { .enumType = GetType(OsStatus)})
End Using
```

```
@Html.BeginForm()
@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.status, "Enum", New With { .enumType = GetType(OsStatus)})
```

None of the above worked.

The code for my template is as follows

```
@ModelType String

@code

    Dim options As IEnumerable(Of OsStatus)
    options = [Enum].GetValues(ViewData("enumType")).Cast(Of OsStatus)()


    Dim list As List(Of SelectListItem) = 
            (from value in options 
            select new SelectListItem With { _
                .Text = value.ToString(), _
                .Value = value.ToString(), _
                .Selected = value.Equals(Model) _
            }).ToList()
    End If
End Code

@Html.DropDownList(Model, list)
```

After calling a `.BeginForm` method, my template is still called, but the `Model` property inside my template is `null`.

ANY ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see at least 4 issues with your editor template:

- You have an `End If` without an opening `If` so your editor template is likely to throw an exception
- In order to determine the selected value you are comparing an enum value to a string: `value.Equals(Model)` whereas you should be comparing string with string: `value.ToString().Equals(Model)`
- When rendering your dropdownlist you are using your `Model` value as name whereas you should be using an empty string in order to have correct name for this dropdownlist from the parent property.
- Your editor template is now tied to the `OsStatus` enum as you are casting to it inside it. It would have been better to make this editor template a little more generic and reusable.

Here's the correct way:

```
@ModelType String

@code
    Dim options = [Enum].GetValues(ViewData("enumType")).Cast(Of Object)()

    Dim list As List(Of SelectListItem) =
            (From value In options
            Select New SelectListItem With { _
                .Text = value.ToString(), _
                .Value = value.ToString(), _
                .Selected = value.ToString().Equals(Model) _
            }).ToList()
End Code

@Html.DropDownList("", list)
```

And the correct way to invoke it is:

```
@Using Ajax.BeginForm("New", "Os", Nothing)
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.status, "Enum", New With { .enumType = GetType(OsStatus)})
End Using
```

or:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("New", "Os", Nothing)
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.status, "Enum", New With { .enumType = GetType(OsStatus)})
End Using
```

Now when rendering this view make sure that the controller action actually passed a model and have the `status` string property set to some string value that is contained within the enum so that the correct option could be automatically pre-selected in the dropdown.

Comment: You are right on every point. But..

1. The `End If` was result of lack of attention while cutting down the code for simplicity
2. I fixed the comparison later, but that wasn't that the cause
3. Using the `Model` as the name was an error too but wasn't causing the issue

Really nice tip on the generalization of the `Cast` (kudos!)

I don't know why but, in short, if I'm not calling a `.BeginForm` method, that template works. If I'm using `.BeginForm` I **HAVE TO** add a condition on the editor to render the dropdown for a null model, which happens when I'm creating an Os.

Thanks!